# Remove unwanted space of JS retrieve variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and its developing. there  takeing values from HTML and save those values in JS variables to pass codiginiter controller. but there are unwanted space with those saved variables. how do i remove that unwanted variable spaces. please find below the code i used and please find the output. thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('#answerpost').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.post('http://localhost/webcw/homepage/saveanswerDetails', {
                    votecount :$("#qvotecount").html(),
                    qid :$("#qno").html(),
                    user: $("#user").html()

                } 

                );

            });

            </script>
```

**OutPut**

```
29                        ->0->
                            hipve
```

Comment: Use [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)?

Comment: $.trim($("#qno").text()) is more compat and typically cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use trim() function. For example:

```
var a = 'test    ';
console.log(a.trim()); // this will output just 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking to parse out text from, but the following regular expression removes all whitespace from a string:

```
.replace(/( )/g, "")
```

So

```
"29                        ->0->".replace(/( )/g, "")
```

Gives you "29->0->".